# Generate XML for <GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">

Tags: c#

Please help me I want generate, using C#, root XML for send to the server.

For similar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
    <Header>
        <MessageDetails>
            <Class>SendDocument</Class>
            <Qualifier>request</Qualifier>
            <Function>submit</Function>
      <TransactionID>5</TransactionID>
            <CorrelationID></CorrelationID>
        </MessageDetails>
        <SenderDetails>
            <IDAuthentication>
                <SenderID>[USER]</SenderID>
                <Authentication>
                    <Method>clear</Method>
                    <Value>[PASS]</Value>
                </Authentication>
            </IDAuthentication>
        </SenderDetails>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Message xmlns="urn:g3.ge:dea:call:SendDocument:v1">
           ................
        </Message>
    </Body>
  </GovTalkMessage>
```

Beforehand thanks for answer

Comment: Just generate a service reference. No need to do SOAP by hand.

Comment: @Paata - do you have an XSD for the envelope wrapper, and for the payload (`Message xmlns=...`)? Also, what protocol are you using? Is this an Xml Web Service (e.g. Pox / Proprietary), or e.g. Queue / File based message?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need to generate XSD schemas for your XML. The Government Gateway should provide XSDs for your particular submission domain. If not, you can generate a reasonably good schema from the XML file by using the Visual Studio XML tools under Create Schema from the XML menu.

Once you have a schema file you can use the XSD.exe tool from the Windows SDK to generate service classes. If you have multiple schema files (say, one for the GovTalkMessage wrapper and one for a particular domain, like Inland Revenue in my example below) you can combine them in one service class file:

If the XSD tool is installed in its typical location you can run this command:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64>xsd.exe /c c:\Schemas\GovTalkMessage.xsd C:\ServiceClasses\IREnvelope.xsd /o:C:\GovTalkApplication
```

Once you have service classes for your XML you can create new objects from your data and serialize them into XML fairly easily. In this code sample I have used AppSettings in the configuration file to store various constant values and a private DataTable called _localData to hold my body data which I am putting into an IR R68 payload (in the  element). I am also using a log4net logger here, which is incidental. The CreateIRBody method is something you will have to write for whatever payload you need to include:

```
   public GovTalkMessage CreateRequestMessage(string env)
        {
            try
            {
                log.Debug("CreateRequestMessage called");
                GovTalkMessageBody Body = new GovTalkMessageBody();

                IR68 ir68 = new IR68(_localData);
                log.Debug("Creating IR68 body ...");

                IRenvelope ire = new IRenvelope();
                ire = ir68.CreateIRBody();

                //serialize ire into XmlElement and then set Body.Any = 

                XmlElement xe = GiftAidSubmissionProcessController.SerializeIREnvelope(ire);
                XmlElement[] XmlElementIRenvelope = new XmlElement[1];
                XmlElementIRenvelope[0] = xe;

                Body.Any = XmlElementIRenvelope;

                //GovTalkDetails

                GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsChannelRoutingChannel Channel = new GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsChannelRoutingChannel();
                Channel.Version = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelVersion"];
                Channel.Product = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelProduct"];
                Channel.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.URI;
                Channel.Item = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelURI"];

                GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsChannelRouting ChannelRouting = new GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsChannelRouting();
                ChannelRouting.Channel = Channel;

                GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsKey Key = new GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsKey();
                Key.Type = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GovTalkDetailsKeyType"];
                Key.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GovTalkDetailsKey"];

                GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetails Details = new GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetails();

                GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsChannelRouting[] ChannelRoutings = 
                    new GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsChannelRouting[1];
                ChannelRoutings[0] = ChannelRouting;
                Details.ChannelRouting = ChannelRoutings;

                GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsKey[] Keys = new GovTalkMessageGovTalkDetailsKey[1];
                Keys[0] = Key;
                Details.Keys = Keys;

                string[] TargetDetails = new string[1];
                TargetDetails[0] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GovTalkDetailsTargetOrganistion"];
                Details.TargetDetails = TargetDetails;

                //GovTalk Header

                GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthentication Authentication = new GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthentication();
                switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderAuthenticationMethod"])
                {
                    case "MD5":
                        Authentication.Method = GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthenticationMethod.MD5;
                        break;
                    case "clear":
                        Authentication.Method = GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthenticationMethod.clear;
                        break;
                    case "W3Csigned":
                        Authentication.Method = GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthenticationMethod.W3Csigned;
                        break;
                }
                Authentication.Role = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderAuthenticationRole"];
                Authentication.Item = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderAuthenticationValue"];

                GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthentication IDAuthentication = new GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthentication();
                IDAuthentication.SenderID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderID"];

                GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthentication[] Authentications = new GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetailsIDAuthenticationAuthentication[1];
                Authentications[0] = Authentication;
                IDAuthentication.Authentication = Authentications;

                GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetails SenderDetails = new GovTalkMessageHeaderSenderDetails();
                SenderDetails.IDAuthentication = IDAuthentication;

                GovTalkMessageHeaderMessageDetails MessageDetails = new GovTalkMessageHeaderMessageDetails();
                MessageDetails.Class = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageDetailsClass"];
                MessageDetails.Qualifier = GovTalkMessageHeaderMessageDetailsQualifier.request;
                MessageDetails.FunctionSpecified = true;
                MessageDetails.Function = GovTalkMessageHeaderMessageDetailsFunction.submit;
                MessageDetails.TransformationSpecified = true;
                MessageDetails.Transformation = GovTalkMessageHeaderMessageDetailsTransformation.XML;
                MessageDetails.GatewayTest = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageDetailsGatewayTest"];
                if (env == "local")
                {
                    MessageDetails.GatewayTimestampSpecified = true;
                    MessageDetails.GatewayTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageDetails.GatewayTimestampSpecified = false;
                    MessageDetails.GatewayTimestamp = DateTime.MinValue; }

                GovTalkMessageHeader Header = new GovTalkMessageHeader();
                Header.MessageDetails = MessageDetails;
                Header.SenderDetails = SenderDetails;

                GovTalkMessage GovTalkMessage = new hmrcclasses.GovTalkMessage();

                GovTalkMessage.EnvelopeVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GovTalkMessageEnvelopeVersion"];
                GovTalkMessage.Header = Header;
                GovTalkMessage.GovTalkDetails = Details;
                GovTalkMessage.Body = Body;

                log.Info("GovTalkMessage created successfully");

                return GovTalkMessage;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy whole XML (CRTL+A CTRL+C)
2. Open Visual Studio and create new Class
3. Click menu - Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes

after that you can use XmlSerializer to generate that XML

```
var entity = new GovTalkMessage();
//fill entity properties with data

var writer = new StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GovTalkMessage));

serializer.Serialize(writer, entity);

var xmlText = writer.ToString();
//and so on...
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a whole XML file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
        <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
        <Header>
            <MessageDetails>
                <Class>SendDocument</Class>
                <Qualifier>request</Qualifier>
                <Function>submit</Function>
                <CorrelationID></CorrelationID>
            </MessageDetails>
            <SenderDetails>
                <IDAuthentication>
                    <SenderID>[USER]</SenderID>
                    <Authentication>
                        <Method>clear</Method>
                        <Value>[PASS]</Value>
                    </Authentication>
                </IDAuthentication>
            </SenderDetails>
        </Header>
        <Body>
            <Message xmlns="urn:g3.ge:dea:call:SendDocument:v1">
                <Container xmlns="http://www.dea.gov.ge/schemas/2011/dx">
                    <Reference>GUID</Reference>
                    <DocDate>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</DocDate>
                    <DocNumber>string</DocNumber>
                    <Persons>
                        <Person>
                            <OriginID>1</OriginID>
                            <FirstName>string</FirstName>
                            <LastName>string</LastName>
                            <Position>string</Position>
                            <PersonType>1</PersonType>
                            <ResolutionText>string (max length: 1000 chars)</ResolutionText>
                            <OrgUnit>string (max length: 4000 chars)</OrgUnit>
                        </Person>
                        <Person>
                            <OriginID>447</OriginID>
                            <FirstName>string</FirstName>
                            <LastName>string</LastName>
                            <Position>string</Position>
                            <PersonType>2</PersonType>
                            <ResolutionText>string (max length: 1000 chars)</ResolutionText>
                            <OrgUnit>string (max length: 4000 chars)</OrgUnit>
                        </Person>
                    </Persons>
                    <Subject>string</Subject>
                    <MainDoc>
                        <Doc>
                            <FileName></FileName>
                            <ContentType></ContentType>
                            <Signature>
                                <Type></Type>
                                <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            </Signature>
                            <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            <DocType></DocType>
                        </Doc>
                    </MainDoc>
                    <RespondTo>
                        <OriginalDoc>
                            <Reference>GUID</Reference>
                            <Type/>
                        </OriginalDoc>
                    </RespondTo>
                    <OriginalReference>GUID</OriginalReference>
                    <AttachedDocs>
                        <Doc>
                            <FileName></FileName>
                            <ContentType></ContentType>
                            <Signature>
                                <Type></Type>
                                <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            </Signature>
                            <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            <DocType></DocType>
                        </Doc>
                        <Doc>
                            <FileName></FileName>
                            <ContentType></ContentType>
                            <Signature>
                                <Type></Type>
                                <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            </Signature>
                            <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            <DocType></DocType>
                        </Doc>
                        <Doc>
                            <FileName></FileName>
                            <ContentType></ContentType>
                            <Signature>
                                <Type></Type>
                                <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            </Signature>
                            <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                            <DocType></DocType>
                        </Doc>
                    </AttachedDocs>
                    <Signature>
                        <Type></Type>
                        <Data>BASE64BINARY</Data>
                    </Signature>
                </Container>
            </Message>
        </Body>
    </GovTalkMessage>
```